# How to create real-time etw consumer for TraceLogging provider(kernel)?

Tags: c++, windows, etw, windows-kernel

I'm trying to create the real-time consumer for the [TraceLogging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/tracelogging-for-kernel-mode-drivers-and-components) provider which declared in driver:

```
TRACELOGGING_DECLARE_PROVIDER(g_etwProvider);
TRACELOGGING_DEFINE_PROVIDER(g_etwProvider, "TraceLoggingProvider", 
    (/*my guid*/));
```

User-mode provider:

```
EVENT_TRACE_LOGFILEA etwTraceSettings{};
char loggerName[]{"TraceLoggingProvider"};
etwTraceSettings.LoggerName = loggerName;
etwTraceSettings.ProcessTraceMode = PROCESS_TRACE_MODE_REAL_TIME | PROCESS_TRACE_MODE_EVENT_RECORD;
etwTraceSettings.EventRecordCallback = MyCallback;
TRACEHANDLE traceHandle = OpenTraceA(&etwTraceSettings);
ProcessTrace(&traceHandle, 1, nullptr, nullptr);
```

[ProcessTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/evntrace/nf-evntrace-processtrace) returns `ERROR_WMI_INSTANCE_NOT_FOUND`. What am I doing wrong?
I tried to call `ProcessTrace` before and after `TraceLoggingRegister` in the driver. Result is the same.

And, for example, [logman](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/logman) can create session before provider registration. I want to do the same. What I must do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create ETW session before `OpenTrace` by [StartTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/evntrace/nf-evntrace-starttracea) and [EnableTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/evntrace/nf-evntrace-enabletrace) functions.